# apiai-starter-app.zip is missing agent.zip

Tags: actions-on-google

I am so excited to kick the tires on this amazing integration.
I am following the instructions on https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/project-agent, and have downloaded https://developers.google.com/actions/downloads/apiai-starter-app.zip. However, the content of the zip is missing agent.zip that the instructions are referencing. Are the instructions correct? Where else can I get agent.zip to accompany the starter app?

Thank you,
Irena

Comment: You can just go to 'import' in API.AI and click on the zip file you downloaded (apiai-starter-app.zip) - it will import all the intents and you could start work on it.

Answer (score 1):

The instructions are the correct. I just downloaded the zip file and it has these json files and folder

[image]

[image]

Can you post your project and the downloaded folder screen shot?

Comment: Here is the content of the unzipped folder. My confusion was due to missing agent.zip file in the folder. The 30 minutes example I cloned from git did contain FactsAboutGoogle.zip that matched the instruction. I can upload the zip in its entirety as suggested above.               ./agent.json
./customDomainsResponses.json
./intents
./intents/deeplink_unknown.json
./intents/help.json
./intents/input_unknown.json
./intents/input_welcome.json
./intents/quit.json
./intents/quit_no - context_ quit-confirmation.json
./intents/quit_yes - context_ quit-confirmation.json
./intents/repeat.json

Comment: @IrenaShai Sorry, it hard to read in this comment 
could you please update your question with this comment ?